# Unity is multiplying the vertex count of my mesh twenty fold when importing it from blender?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, mesh

This is my first time using such a massive mesh as its meant to be terrain but I cannot use Unity's terrain feature to make it. In Blender it shows as just under 20k vertices, yet when I bring it into Unity it shows a staggering 493k. I've never had this problem with a mesh before. Creating the terrain was the first step in this project so there are absolutely no other meshes or objects in the scene beyond two planes that are used for water, yet they aren't the culprit since disabling or deleting them has no noticeable effect on the vertex count.
[image: Blender Screenshot showing total vertex count of 19,129]
[image: Unity Statistics Screenshot showing Verts count of 492.2k]
[image: Empty hierarchy except mesh in question, Directional Light, Player prefab containing canvas elements and a camera, and event system]
As you can see in the images, the vertex count in blender shows 19,129, while in Unity it is 492.2k. My hierarchy is empty except a player prefab containing canvas elements, and a camera, a directional light, and event system.
I have really no idea what could be causing this.

Comment: Do you have a subdivide modifier in on the terrain in blender?

Comment: The mesh itself is from a height map converted into a mesh in Photoshop, from there I used a remesh then decimate modifier to get it into low poly, no subdivision.

Comment: Did you check if you view it in another program if it is the same vertex count as in unity? It could be also happening in the export of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The vertex count from the statistic window includes all vertices in the rendering. A lot of it is probably coming from the camera, which probably includes a skybox, shadows (as the statistic window shows: "Shadow casters: 2"), and depth texture. Try delete everything in your hierarchy except for the terrain, then check again.

Comment: It decreases the count by about 1k, still 491k.

Comment: Then otherwise, it is the change made by the actual importation from Blender to Unity. See [this forum](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1374086/number-of-vertices-of-a-model-is-not-the-same-in-b.html) for full explanation.

Comment: The forum says that vertex increases come from the conversion from quads to tris, which says causes a threefold increase in the importation from blender, but mine is twenty fold? Is there something else or does that explain it and I've just misinterpreted something.

Comment: Then it is probably something else. Just to make sure, try to import the default cube from Blender, if the # seems correct, then maybe it has to do with your actual mesh.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved using framedebugger, this guy did an extensive tips to solve the issue see the link.
https://youtu.be/kxy13kCo4bk

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).